# Python: encounter problems in sentence segmenter, word tokenizer, and part-of-speech tagger

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to read text file into Python, and then do sentence segmenter, word tokenizer, and part-of-speech tagger.

This is my code:

```
file=open('C:/temp/1.txt','r')
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(file)
sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
```

When I try just second command, it displayed error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(file)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 76, in sent_tokenize
return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1217, in tokenize
return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1262, in sentences_from_text
sents = [text[sl] for sl in self._slices_from_text(text)]
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1269, in _slices_from_text
for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Another try: 
When I try just one sentence such as "A yellow dog barked at the cat"
The first three commands work, but the last line, I got this error:(I wonder if I didn't download packages completely?)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load
resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

Comment: See my updated answer below. You need to be very careful about specifying exactly what you're changing in the input in order to get useful advice. It's clear that `nltk.sent_tokenize` accepts only string input, and not `file` objects, and you're not clearly differentiating the two.

Comment: can you please post an excerpt of how your `C:/temp/1.txt` look like?

Answer (score 2):

Um... are you sure the error is in the **second** line?

You appear to be using single-quote and comma characters other than the standard ASCII `'` and `,` characters:

```
file=open(‘C:/temp/1.txt’，‘r’) # your version (WRONG)
file=open('C:/temp/1.txt', 'r') # right
```

Python shouldn't even be able to compile this. Indeed, when I try it it barfs due to a syntax error.

**UPDATE:** You posted a corrected version with proper syntax. The error message from the traceback is a pretty straightforward one: the function you're calling seems to expect a chunk of text as its parameter, rather than a file object. Although I don't know anything about NLTK specifically, spending five seconds on Google [confirms this](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize).

Try something like this:

```
file = open('C:/temp/1.txt','r')
text = file.read() # read the contents of the text file into a variable
result1 = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
result2 = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in result1]
result3 = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in result2]
```

**UPDATE:** I renamed `sentences` to `result`1/2/3 because of the confusion over what the code is actually doing due to repeatedly overwriting the same variable. This **does not** affect the semantics, just clarifies that the second line actually has an effect on the final `result3`.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistyping. In my code, I use ' instead ‘. But I still got this type of error.

Comment: So do you still get the **exact same** error (indicating that the problem is in the second line)?

Comment: Just the first line become:File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>.Other error is the same. And I had another try in my problem, I edited my problem.

Comment: Dan, under your mentorship, I successfully run the first four commands(based on your code). But when I run the last command, it keep giving me the error I described in my edited problem whether I use a sentence, or the text documents.

Comment: Why don't you do the following? Add `print sentences` statements after each line starting with `sentences = ...`. That way, you'll see the intermediate output. Then carefully check that the format of the input  to the last line matches the expected format of the input according to [the docs for `pos_tag`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.pos_tag)

Comment: @Dan, looping through the sentences twice is unnecessary

Comment: @alvas: why is it unnecessary? Each line is processing the data in a different way (look at the NLTK docs), so how can you say it's necessary without understanding the OP's intent for the code?

Comment: because the resulting sentences variable is overwritten by `pos_tag()` after `word_tokenize()`

Comment: @alvas, that's wrong. It's not a clear coding style at all (copied from the OP), but the result of each value assigned to `sentences` is reused in the following line. So the middle line cannot simply be removed because it affects the input to the third line.

Comment: @Dan, granted the new variable names, that makes more sense =)

Answer (score 0):

First open the file and then read it:

```
filename = 'C:/temp/1.txt'
infile = open(filename, 'r')
text = infile.read()
```

then chain the tools up in nltk as such:

```
tagged_words = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(i) for i in sent_tokenize(text)]
```