# word_tokenize TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, tokenize

When calling `word_tokenize` I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1322,
    in _slices_from_text for match in
    self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I have a large text file (1500.txt) from which I want to remove stop words.
My code is as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

with open('E:\\Book\\1500.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as File_1500:
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    words = word_tokenize(File_1500)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
    print(filtered_sentence)
```

Comment: what error did you get mate

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Can you give a small sample input, output, and expected output.

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1322, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: What's the whole error?

Comment: Oh, it's saying it wants a string, but you're passing it a file. Pass it `File_1500.read()` to give it a string.

Comment: @PeterWood my question is that how should i remove stop words from a text file. Like i dont need "the", "a", "that" etc words. I am using Python 3.4.2. and the error message is:-

Comment: @PeterWood you solved the problem :)

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1322, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @SaqibAlam change this `words = word_tokenize(File_1500)` to this `words = word_tokenize(File_1500.read())`

Comment: @PeterWood thanks bro. Actually i am new to Python :)

Comment: @VigneshKalai thanks a lot bro :)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273662/python-encounter-problems-in-sentence-segmenter-word-tokenizer-and-part-of-sp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input for `word_tokenize` is a document stream sentence, i.e. a list of strings, e.g. `['this is sentence 1.', 'that's sentence 2!']`.

The `File_1500` is a `File` object not a list of strings, that's why it's not working.

To get a list of sentence strings, first you have to read the file as a string object `fin.read()`, then use `sent_tokenize` to split the sentence up (I'm assuming that your input file is not sentence tokenized, just a raw textfile).

Also, it's better / more idiomatic to tokenize a file this way with NLTK:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

with open('E:\\Book\\1500.txt', "r", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as fin:
    for sent in sent_tokenize(fin.read()):
        words = word_tokenize(sent)
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
        print(filtered_sentence)
```