# word_tokenize in nltk not taking a list of string as argument

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

music_comments = [['So cant you just run the bot outside of the US? ', ''], ["Just because it's illegal doesn't mean it will stop. I hope it actually gets enforced. ", ''], ['Can they do something about all the fucking bots on Tinder next?   \n\nEdit: Holy crap my inbox just blew up ', '']]

print(word_tokenize(music_comments[1]))
```

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773157/word-tokenize-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer) which says to pass a list of strings to word_tokenize, but in my case after running the above I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(word_tokenize(music_comments[1]))
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 109, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 94, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in <listcomp>
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Shraddheya Shendre\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1289, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What is the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: You pass ONE string to `word_tokenize()`, not a list. That's what the code in the linked question does too. (And of course the answer to your question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are feeding a list with two items into `tokenize()`:

```
["Just because it's illegal doesn't mean it will stop. I hope it actually gets enforced. ", '']
```

i.e the sentence and an empty string.

Changing your code to this should do the trick:

```
print(word_tokenize(music_comments[1][0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def word_tokenize(self, s):
    """Tokenize a string to split off punctuation other than periods"""
    return self._word_tokenizer_re().findall(s)
```

this is part of the '[Source code for nltk.tokenize.punkt](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html#PunktLanguageVars.word_tokenize)'.

The input of function `word_tokenize()` should be a string,not a list.